# Key Bind Multiple Entry Widgets to One Function Which Updates Unique Variables

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have multiple tkinter Entry widgets, and I would like to record the value if the user hits enter or clicks the submit button. I am currently binding `<Return>` to definitions unique to each Entry widget like so:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Variable I want to update
var1 = None
var2 = None

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')

def get_val1_on_enter(entered_value):
    global var1
    entered_value = entry1.get()
    var1 = entered_value
    print('Value1: {}'.format(var1))

def get_val2_on_enter(entered_value):
    global var2
    entered_value = entry2.get()
    var2 = entered_value
    print('Value1: {}'.format(var2))

def submit():
    global var1, var2
    value1 = entry1.get()
    var1 = value1
    value2 = entry2.get()
    var2 = value2
    print('Value 1: {}'.format(var1))
    print('Value 2: {}'.format(var2))

# Entry Fields
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()
entry1.bind('<Return>', get_val1_on_enter)

entry2 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()
entry2.bind('<Return>', get_val2_on_enter)

# Submit Button
submit_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit)
submit_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to have one definition and use it multiple times rather than use a separate definition for each entry field. Is there a way to write and call a definition that could be used for both entry fields?

I am also curious why the `entered_value` input for `def get_val1_on_enter(entered_value):` is necessary for the key bind to work? This is what is stopping me from writing a definition with an argument to specify which variable to update, for example `def get_value(variable_to_update):`.

Comment: When using `.bind(...)`, `tkinter` calls your function with an `event` argument. It tells you stuff about the event like what keys were pressed, what widget caused the event... If you change `def submit()` to `def submit(event=None)`, you can use it instead of your `get_val1_on_enter` and your `get_val2_on_enter` functions.

Comment: Is this for a log-in form?

Comment: @CoolCloud. No this is not for a log-in form, so it shouldn't need any form of security for a password etc. It is just for users to input float values for multiple variables which change how a .txt file is edited.

Comment: Are the two data related? You could store them in a dictionary then

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to record the value if the user hits enter, then binding
>  to definitions unique to each Entry.

The problem can be fixed.

You don't have to write too many functions for each `Entry` widget. Just one function will do good job.

I have removed three functions, in order to reduce less coding.

Snippet modified to reduce less coding:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Variable I want to update
var1 = None
var2 = None

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')

 
# Entry Fields
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()
#entry1.bind('<Return>', get_val1_on_enter)

entry2 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()
#entry2.bind('<Return>', get_val2_on_enter)

# Submit Button
#submit_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Submit')
#submit_button.pack()


def go_to_next_entry(event, entry_list, this_index):
    next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entry_list)
    print(entry_list[this_index].get())
    entry_list[next_index].focus_set()

entries = [child for child in root.winfo_children() if isinstance(child, ttk.Entry)]
for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, idx=idx: go_to_next_entry(e, entries, idx))


root.mainloop()
```