# Tkinter endless looping through entry and not exiting the loop, as well as cursor not moving to next field

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I am writing an app using tkinter. In my program I want to get two separate inputs from the user:
[image]

The picture is the current state of the gui of my app. When running the code, the cursor focuses on the first entry field. The code allows me to enter values in both field (I can enter a value in the second field if I manually move the cursor there). The values are appended to a list in a for-loop in my code. My problem is that I can't seem to get out of the loop - if I submit a new input in one of the fields, the new value is appended. I would like for the program to exit the for-loop when both variables are not none, as well as for the cursor to move automatically to the next field after entering a value. How do I achieve this? I would much appreciate any help!

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Gui:

    # Text arrays
    ...
    _output: list
    _bits: list

    def __init__(self, root):
        """ Initiating root and reused variables"""

        self.root = root
        ...

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="8 8 24 24", relief="groove")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=EW)
        self.mainframe = mainframe
        ...


        # Calling functions
        self.greetings(0)
        self.jql_query()
        self.__exit__()


    def greetings(self, n):
        """ Creates a greeting's textbox at top """
        ...
        return base

    def jql_query(self):
        """ Entry widget for creating jql-query """

        input1 = "Enter name of main folder in summary:"
        input2 = "Enter name of sub folder in summary:"
        inputs = [input1, input2]

        font1 = ...
        font2 = ...

        self.head = StringVar()
        self.sub = StringVar()
        self._summary = [self.head, self.sub]
        self._output = []

        row = self.greetings(2)
        for ind, line in enumerate(self._summary):
            sum_label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text=inputs[ind], background='#2E3135', foreground='white', font=font1)
            sum_label.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=EW)

            en = Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=line, bd=3, background="#484D51", fg='white', font=font2, width=20, relief='flat')
            en.grid(column=2, row=row, sticky=EW)
            en.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

            butt = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Submit", command=lambda x=ind: self.print_output(x))
            butt.grid(column=3, row=row, padx=10, sticky=W)

            self._output.append(en)
            self._output[ind].focus()
            self.root.bind("<Return>", self.print_output)

            ind += 1
            row += 1

    def print_output(self, *args):
        """ Getting input to jql """
        # Need to add a statement that tells the program to exit the for-loop when the value is not None!

        self._bits = []
        i = 0
        while i <= len(self._output)-1:
            for line, entry in enumerate(self._output):
                bit = entry.get()
                self._bits.append(bit)
                line += 1
                i += 1
        return self._bits


    def __exit__(self):
        """ Exit program"""

        row = self.greetings(4)
        ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Quit", command=self.root.destroy).grid(column=9, row=row)


root = Tk()
gui = Gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I have omitted bits of the code that I deem not relevant for the problem at hand with "...".

Answer (score 0):

On line 64, you couldn't called `self.root.bind`, and cannot use callback `self.print_output` function.

What are you seeking for is `en = Entry(...)`. That's why you're looking for `Entry` widgets.

Replace `self.root` to  `en.bind`, then use `lambda` on line 64:

```
self.root.bind("<Return>", self.print_output)
```

to:

```
en.bind("<Return>",lambda funct1:en.focus())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did partly solve the problem with the cursor. "Enter" doesn't equal giving an input anymore, it just swaps input field so I think I somehow need to bind it to the 'print_output' function anyways. Would that be doable?

Comment: How do you mean? Could you possibly elaborate? I don't have any variable named "var", and should I implement it in the for loop to exit it or should it be in the __exit__-function?

Edit: I think your answer disappeared when I rewrote and posted my comment at the exact same time as you posted.

Comment: You already have StringVar() To use that if self.head.get=="": in exit function. Btw, I'm on holiday weekend. To see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277167/key-bind-multiple-entry-widgets-to-one-function-which-updates-unique-variables/76620273#7662027

Comment: I'm sorry for disturbing you on your vacation, but I'm not getting it to work.. I can't seem to figure out how I can get the program to focus on the entry element and bind to the print_output function, as well as how to exit the loop when the list is not empty anymore. I figure that a loop incorporating entries is very different from a "regular" loop, where you can easily break the loop  just by "while i<n:".

Comment: Are you running pycharm, pytorch, etc?

Comment: I am using pycharm.

Comment: Did u upgrade pycharm?

Comment: I downloaded the community edition in the end of June so I should have the latest version.

Comment: Can u go into chat?

Comment: How do I go into chat?

Comment: On top right. or you will will see red box

Comment: Seems like I don't have enough reputations.. :( I can see your messages but I can't answer.

Comment: OIC. Thank. Are you running MacOS or Ubuntu, etc?

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: Have u try any other example to run on pycharm?

Comment: If you mean to ask if I have tried other programs in pycharm then yes, but this is my first code with tkinter.

Comment: Then I'd say the answer is no.

Comment: I could skip the function of return = giving input + changing input fields, but do you know how I can exit the for-loop? I'd say that that is priority.

Comment: I think I have localized one error. The "ttk.Button" doesn't work together with the "Entry(...)", which makes up for not submitting an input when pressing return. I implemented the "Entry(...)" instead of "ttk.Entry(...)" as I didn't find a way to change the background colour of the entry field.

Comment: U need to add style = ttk.Style() then style.configure("BW.TEntry", foreground="black", background="white")

Comment: Oh! Thank you! The foreground-part worked but the background is left unchanged. I'll just keep the default. As for the what seems like an "endless" loop, maybe that will be solved if I continue to build other widgets and call them. I consider the problem solved, thank you so much Supra-san!

Comment: Use .config or configure.....  en.config(background='red') to change colour.

Comment: I needed to change the "fieldbackground" and not the "background", my bad.